# Dependencies not installing correctly during Heroku deploy?

Tags: php, git, heroku, composer-php

I'm trying to deploy a PHP app to Heroku but I don't think my dependencies are installing properly.

When I run `git push heroku master` I see these lines:

```
Installing dependencies...
Composer version 1.2.4 2016-12-06 22:00:51
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
  -Installing components/jquery (3.1.1)
   Downloading: 100%
  -Installing fortawesome/font-awesome (v4.7.0)
   Downloading: 100%
  -Installing phpmailer/phpmailer (v5.2.22)
   Downloading: 100%
```

No errors or anything. But when I open the heroku app after it's been deployed I have all kinds of console errors for jquery not being found.

I looked in developer tools in the sources tab and see a folder named `vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/css` (that's the actual whole folder name) with the file `font-awesome.min.css` in it ... but shouldn't they all be installed in a `vendor` folder?

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You should ignore your `composer.lock` file, that file can cause big trouble on creating new app in heroku, openshift, or other PAAS/SAAS, like what you have experienced.

Comment: That's _awful_ advice, @RendyEkoPrastiyo. In most cases it is _extremely important_ to [track `composer.lock`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file). If you don't you can end up with different versions of libraries in development and production, which can cause all kinds of large and small bugs. In fact, [Heroku will reject applications that include dependencies in `composer.json` but lack `composer.lock`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation).

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking, Timothy. You say, "but shouldn't they all be installed in a `vendor` folder?", yet the CSS file you found is in `vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/css/`. It _is_ in a `vendor/` folder.

Comment: lol Chris you're right I must have been stupid tired when I asked this. I was beyond confused. An update, my project requirements changed and I didn't need to use PHP in my project (it was a simple landing page with a PHP contact form). I switched over to using npm and everything installed correctly. Still not sure what happened here though.

Comment: @TimothyFisher, what are the exact errors you were getting? How are you trying to load jQuery in your code? How are you using it?

Comment: Everything was working locally. I had paths like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" />` however when Heroku did the app build it seemed like the files weren't getting installed at all. Console log errors were all that they couldn't find the requested files.